# In IIS 8.5, is there a setting in the Manager GUI that adds the Location and Authentication tags to the applicationHost.config file?

Tags: authentication, iis-8.5

I've inherited a IIS 8.5 installation with a lengthy `applicationHost.config` file; I'm not familiar with all the options and am trying not to mess with it as it is working.

When I set up a new web application, to get it work, I'm having to go into `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

and manually add the following for each application:

```
    <location path="Default Web Site/MyNewAppPath">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                    <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Or I get an error - "Access is denied   Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration..."
Lots of posts/comments saying to fix it this way by manually adding the location and other tags, but this seems hacky.

**Isn't there an option/function inside IIS Manager somewhere that handles these tags?**

FYI IIS Manager is adding below tags to the config file (on its own) for each app.  Hoping somehow it can do similar for the location etc tags.

```
<application path="/MyNewAppPath" applicationPool=".NET 4.5">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyNewAppPath" />
 </application>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "this seems hacky"? That's not hacky at all. IIS Manager never allows you to choose when to generate location tags (unless you use its Configuration Editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-application's authentication are only allowed in applicationhost.config by default. If you go to config manager, you will see this

[image]

If you try to set it in other place like root `web.config` or `<location path='webapp'>`, IIS will report the application has already been locked and everything grayed out.

[image]

You can set authentication via IIS manager or command line and it will add these configuration to applicationhost.config automatically. I think this is just common operation instead of hacky.

Comment: Thanks for lead!  For others, full path to that settings area is `system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication`.